# After commit on GitHub using Intellij IDEA nothing changes on the site

Tags: git, intellij-idea

After commiting the project onto GitHub pressing "Commit" button using Intellij IDEA, and confirming uploading and even seeing the result message about "Successful commit", I can't see any changes on the site.
I'm facing with this 2nd time. After the first time, I've deleted the repository on the site and reuploaded my project. Curious, that my previous version of project was saved after all, meaning that I didn't recreate repository but commited the new changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you choose "Commit and Push"?

Comment: A commit changes your **local** repo. If you want to share the change, you have to **push** it, as well.

Comment: @DanielMann Not in `Intellij IDEA` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't choose `Commit and Push` you need to push your changes to the remote repo.

From [Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#push):

> Press Ctrl+Shift+K or choose VCS | Git | Push from the main menu. The Push Commits dialog opens showing all Git repositories (for multi-repository projects) and listing all commits made in the current branch in each repository since the last push.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I worked with SVN before so I didn't need to push the updates after commit so I fell myself dumb a bit :D
Thanks a lot!